# How can I get updated system DPI information from X11 in a C program?

Tags: c, x11, sdl-2, highdpi

I'm trying to create a DPI aware app which responds to user requested DPI change events by resizing the window.

The program in question is created in C and uses SDL2, however to retrieve system DPI information I use xlib directly, as the SDL DPI support in X11 is lacking.

I found two ways to get the correct DPI information on program startup, both involving getting Xft.dpi information from Xresource: one is to use XGetDefault(display, "Xft", "dpi"), while the other is to use XResourceManagerString, XrmGetStringDatabase and XrmGetResource. Both of them return the correct DPI value when the program is created.

The problem is, if the user changes the system scale while the program is running, both XGetDefault abd XrmGetResource still return the old DPI value even though when I run "xrdb -query | grep Xft.dpi" the value has indeed changed.

Does anyone know a way to get the updated Xft.dpi value?

Answer (score 2):

First off it must be noted that the value of the `Xft.dpi` resource isn't necessarily accurate -- it depends on whether the system and or user login scripts have correctly set it or not.

Also it is important to remember that the `Xft.dpi` resource is intended to be used by the **Xft** library, not by arbitrary programs looking for the screen resolution.

The `Xft.dpi` resource can be set as follows.  This example effectively only deals with a display with a single screen, and note that it uses `xdpyinfo`.  This also shows how it might not be exact, but could be rounded.  Finally this example shows calculation of both the horizontal and vertical resolution, but **Xft** really only wants the horizontal resolution:

```sh
SCREENDPI=$(xdpyinfo | sed -n 's/^[ ]*resolution:[ ]*\([^ ][^ ]*\) .*$/\1/p;//q')
SCREENDPI_X=$(expr "$SCREENDPI" : '\([0-9]*\)x')
SCREENDPI_Y=$(expr "$SCREENDPI" : '[0-9]*x\([0-9]*\)')
# N.B.:  If true screen resolution is within 10% of 100DPI it makes the most
# sense to claim 100DPI to avoid font-scaling artifacts for bitmap fonts.
if expr \( $SCREENDPI_X / 100 = 1 \) \& \( $SCREENDPI_X % 100 \<= 10 \) >/dev/null; then
    FontXDPI=100
fi
if expr \( $SCREENDPI_Y / 100 = 1 \) \& \( $SCREENDPI_Y % 100 \<= 10 \) >/dev/null; then
    FontYDPI=100
fi
echo "Xft.dpi: ${FontYDPI}" | xrdb -merge
```

I really wish I knew why **Xft** didn't at least try to find out the screen's resolution itself instead of relying all of the time on its "dpi" resource being set, but I've found that the current implementation only uses the resource setting, so something like the above is actually always necessary to set the resource properly (and further one must also make sure the X Server itself has been properly configured with the correct physical screen dimensions).

From a C program you want to do just what `xdpyinfo` itself does and skip all the nonsense about **Xft**'s resources.  Here's the `xdpyinfo` code paraphrased:

```c
Display *dpy;
dpy = XOpenDisplay(displayname);
for (scr = 0; scr < ScreenCount(dpy); scr++) {
    int xres, yres;

    /*
     * there are 2.54 centimeters to an inch; so there are 25.4 millimeters.
     *
     *     dpi = N pixels / (M millimeters / (25.4 millimeters / 1 inch))
     *         = N pixels / (M inch / 25.4)
     *         = N * 25.4 pixels / M inch
     */
    xres = ((((double) DisplayWidth(dpy, scr)) * 25.4) /
        ((double) DisplayWidthMM(dpy, scr))) + 0.5;
    yres = ((((double) DisplayHeight(dpy, scr)) * 25.4) /
        ((double) DisplayHeightMM(dpy, scr))) + 0.5;
}
XCloseDisplay(dpy);
```

Note also that if you are for some odd reason scaling your whole display (e.g. with `xrandr`), then you *should* want the fonts to scale equally with everything else.  It's just a horrible bad hack to use whole-screen scaling to scale just the fonts, especially when for most things it's simpler to just tell the application to use properly scaled fonts that will display at a constant on-screen point size (which is exactly what **Xft** uses the "dpi" resource to do).  I'm guessing Ubuntu does something stupid to change the screen resolution, e.g. using `xrandr` to scale up the apparent size of icons and other on-screen widgets without applications having to know about screen size and resolution, then it has to lie to **Xft** by rewriting the `Xft.dpi` resource.

Note that if you avoid whole-screen scaling then applications that don't use **Xft** can still get proper font scaling by correctly requesting a properly scaled font, i.e. even with bitmap fonts you can get them scaled to the proper physical on-screen size by using the screen's actual resolution in the font-spec.  E.g. continuing from the above shell fragment:

```sh
# For pre-Xft applications we can specify physical font text sizes IFF we also tell
# it the screen's actual resolution when requesting a font.  Note the use of the
# rounded values here.
#
DecentDeciPt="80"
DecentPt="8"
export DecentDeciPt DecentPt
#
# Best is to arrange one's font-path to get the desired one first, but....
# If you know the name of a font family that you like and you can be sure
# it is installed and in the font-path somewhere....
#
DefaultFontSpec='-*-liberation mono-medium-r-*-*-*-${DecentDeciPt}-${FontXDPI}-${FontYDPI}-m-*-iso10646-1'
export DefaultFontSpec
#
# For Xft we have set the Xft.dpi resource so this allows the physical font size to
# be specified (e.g. with Xterm's "-fs" option) and for a decent scalable font
# to be chosen:
#
DefaultFTFontSpec="-*-*-medium-r-*-*-*-*-0-0-m-*-iso10646-1"
DefaultFTFontSpecL1="-*-*-medium-r-*-*-*-*-0-0-m-*-iso8859-1"
export DefaultFTFontSpec DefaultFTFontSpecL1

# Set a default font that should work for everything
#
eval echo "*font: ${DefaultFontSpec}" | xrdb -merge
```

Finally here's an example of starting an `xterm` (that's been compiled to use **Xft**) with the above settings (i.e. the `Xft.dpi` resource and the shell variables above) to show text at physical size of 10.0 Points on the screen:

```
xterm -fs 10 -fa $DefaultFTFontSpec
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way to do exactly what I wanted, even though it's rather hackish.

The solution (using `XLib`) is to create a new, temporary connection to the X server using `XOpenDisplay` and `XCloseDisplay`, and poll the resource information from that new connection.

The reason this is needed is because X fetches the resource information only once per new connection, and never updates it. Therefore, by opening a new connection, X will get the updated `xresource` data, which can then be used for the old main connection.

Be mindful that constantly opening and closing new X connections may not be great for performance, so only do it when you absolutely need to. In my case, since the window has borders, I only check for DPI changes when the title height has changed, as a DPI change will change the size of your title border due to font size differences.

Comment: how did you get the title height change event? thanks.

Comment: It has been a while so I don't recall very well, but it was either during window move or window resize event. DPI change triggers a window resize (or move...?) event and changes the title bar height. So by comparing the old title bar height with the new I could tell whether the move/resize as due to the user moving/resizing the window or a possible DPI change.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use xdpyinfo(1); on my system it outputs, among a lot of other things:

```
  dimensions:    1280x1024 pixels (332x250 millimeters)
  resolution:    98x104 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
```

I don't know whether it can help you because I don't know how do you change the DPI of your screen, but chances are it works. Good luck!

--- UPDATE after comment ---
In a comment below from the OP, it is said that "there is a setting to change the DPI"... still I don't know which. Anyway, I tried Ctrl+Alt+Plus and Ctrl+Alt+Minus to change the resolution of the X server on the fly. After having changed the resolution, and seeing everything bigger than before, I ran xdpyinfo again. IT DIDN'T WORK: still the same output. But may be the method you use (which?) instead works...

Comment: On Ubuntu and Linux Mint (the only distros I tried), you can change a setting to scale the windows to 1x, 2x or 3x. Those update Xfi.dpi. Thanks for the suggestion, but getting the monitor dimensions is not ideal because the user may choose different scales regardless of the monitor's physical DPI.

Comment: @JoséCadete see the updated answer. Anyway, you can just try, no?

Comment: In Ubuntu, to change the DPI, you go to Preferences > Devices > Display > Scale. I think the option only appears in monitors with certain resolutions, anyway it's the setting that appears in the image in the following link: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/8bt4eg/oh_cool_i_can_scale_my_display_300_but_not_125/

Comment: @JoséCadete I am more bare-metal... but those 200% 300% scaling could be a totally desktop manager thing instead of "bare-metal" X11. I mean, Ubuntu especially, and many desktop managers try to hide the details of the system, which can be good for the user, but a pain for developers. So I don't know...

Comment: I guess you're right, and also Wayland uses a totally different method. Guess I'll wait until things become more consistent/SDL improves DPI support...